# Update Single Item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

When a single item is pressed in my RecyclerView, I show Bottom Sheet where I edit the contents of that item and when user saves it, I make an object of all the views edited and then send back that object to ListFragment and then I get that object in `onBindViewHolder` and then access the Views and try to set the value on those views from that object, *What happens is RecyclerView changes all of the list items' views but not that specific item that was selected!!!*

I have looked around for this problem's solution for 3 days now but have not come around one working solution

**Please tell me what I'm doing wrong!**

Here's my `onBindViewHolder`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: HostelitesHolder, position: Int) {
            val currentStudentItem = hostelites[position]

            holder.bind(currentStudentItem)

            //onClickListener for when some item is long-pressed.
            holder.parentConstraintLayout.setOnLongClickListener {
                holder.parentConstraintLayoutLongPressed(currentStudentItem)

                return@setOnLongClickListener true
            }
}
```

**The bind() function**

```
fun bind(student: Student) {
            this.student = student
            hosteliteNameTv.text = this.student.stuName

            //Trying to update long-pressed item.
            sharedViewModel.hosteliteMessObj.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                hostelitePaymentMadeTv.text = it.paymentMade
                hosteliteRoomNumTv.text = it.roomNumber
                if (it.messStatus) {
                    hosteliteMessOnStatusIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.mess_status_off_ic)
                } else {
                    hosteliteMessOnStatusIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.mess_status_off_ic)
                }
            }
        }
```

**The parentConstraintLayoutLongPressed() function**

```
sharedViewModel.messManagerObj.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
                if (it.isMessManager && !it.isStudent) {
                    //If user is mess manager, then he's shown [EditUserBottomSheetFragmet] so he can edit user details.
                    val editUserBottomSheetFragment = EditUserBottomSheetFragment()
                    editUserBottomSheetFragment.show(
                        parentFragmentManager,
                        editUserBottomSheetFragment.tag
                    )
                } else { //Not a messmanager
                }
            }

            //The long pressed view item is then saved to shared view model for bottom sheet fragment to edit its contents.
            sharedViewModel.saveStudent(hostelite)
```